# how to Share Multiple image to instagram story from react-native app

Tags: react-native

how to share Image to instagram story from app using react-native-share library and using share.open() method.

for single image using share.singleShare() method is working

I tried with react-native-share library

Comment: Anybody who has done this please help me i was stuck from last two days

Comment: have you achieved anything with that ? :)